# Spark: how to get top 5 rec using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, bigdata

I am converting on of the MR job in Spark, and stuck at where I need to collect data which is not in RDD, but in scala tree map. Use case is to find top 5 countries by sum of bars(field 8) and strips(field 9) in flag. so I get the extracting data from source and saving it in tree map.

Please advice solution or new approach to solve this problem.

**Sample Input:**

```
UK,3,4,245,56,1,1,0,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,red,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,white,red
Uruguay,2,3,178,3,2,0,0,9,3,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,white,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,white,white
US-Virgin-Isles,1,4,0,0,1,1,0,0,6,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,white,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,white,white
USA,1,4,9363,231,1,1,0,13,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,white,0,0,0,1,50,0,0,0,0,0,blue,red
```

**MR map/reduce:**

```
public static class StripeBarMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    private TreeMap<IntWritable, Text> Top5 = new TreeMap<IntWritable,Text>();

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String [] flags = value.toString().split(",");

        Top5.put(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(flags[7]) + Integer.parseInt(flags[8])), new Text(flags[0]));

        if(Top5.size() > 5){
            Top5.remove(Top5.firstKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void cleanup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for ( IntWritable count : Top5.keySet()){
            context.write(count, Top5.get(count));
        }
    }
}

public  static class StripeBarReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.print("reducer received: " + key.toString() + " --> ");

        for(Text country: values)
        context.write(new Text(country), new Text(key));
    }
}
```

**Spark Job**

```
    val inputFile = "Data\\country\\flag.data"

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Top 5 Countries by Sum of bars and strips in flag").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val txtFileLines = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()

    var tm = TreeMap(1 -> "one")

    val Tops =  txtFileLines.map(_.split(","))
                            .map{ s => 
                                  if(tm.size > 5){
                                    tm -= tm.firstKey
                                    }
                                   tm += ((s(7).toInt + s(8).toInt) -> s(0))
                                    }
                           //.sortBy( x => x.toString(), ascending = false, 1).saveAsTextFile("output\\country\\byStripsBar")
                           //.reduce(tm.keys.foreach { x => ($x._1, $x._2) })
```

**Solution:**
I guess following same approach as mapreduce job was not appropriate. I solved the problem using sortBy:

```
val inputFile = "Data\\country\\flag.data"

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Top 5 Countries by Sum of bars and strips in flag").setMaster("local")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val txtFileLines = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()

val Strips =  txtFileLines.map(_.split(","))
                         .map(line => (line(0) + "," + (line(7).toInt + line(8).toInt)))
                         .sortBy(x => x.split(",")(1).trim().toInt, ascending=false)
                         .take(5)
                       //.saveAsTextFile("output\\country\\byStripsBar")

 Strips.foreach { line => println(line) }
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Where in the code do you have a problem?

Comment: Problem: in Sprk job (see commented line that I tried as solution but doesnt give me desired results) Question: How to get data from scala TreeMap (that is extracted from RDD), and make RDD to run reducer. so `Tops` map step fills in `tm` TreeMap, now I want to use values in `tm` to get final output or pass values of `tm` to make new RDD for reduce step.

Comment: My solution stores all records from RDD in sorted order so first 5 recs are top 5 countries but I want to store only first 5 records - is it possible to convert collections[`take(5)`] in RDD?

Comment: Sounds like you want `RDD.top` "def
top(num: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Array[T]
Returns the top k (largest) elements from this RDD as defined by the specified implicit Ordering[T] and maintains the ordering.". Your question was very unclear - despite the title it has nothing to do with `TreeMap`, it seems, since your solution doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `sortBy` and `take()`:

```
val inputFile = "Data\\country\\flag.data"

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Top 5 Countries by Sum of bars and strips in flag").setMaster("local")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val txtFileLines = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()

val Strips =  txtFileLines.map(_.split(","))
                         .map(line => (line(0) + "," + (line(7).toInt + line(8).toInt)))
                         .sortBy(x => x.split(",")(1).trim().toInt, ascending=false)
                         .take(5)

Strips.foreach { line => println(line) }

sc.parallelize(Strips, 1).saveAsTextFile("output\\country\\byStripsBar")
```